# How to download kendo grid excel sheet with binding fields column?

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

This is my columns. Here the first column I bound three fields. When I download this to an excel sheet it comes only name and upc fields.

```
  <kendo-grid-column title="{{ 'MPG/PartNumber/Size' | translate}}" width="250">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
  <span>{{ dataItem.manufactureCode }}</span>
  <span>{{ dataItem.partNo }}</span>
  <span>{{ dataItem.size }}</span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
  <input [formControl]="formGroup.get('manufactureCode')" class="k-textbox boxtext">
  <input [formControl]="formGroup.get('partNo')" class="k-textbox boxtext">
  <input [formControl]="formGroup.get('size')" class="k-textbox boxtext">
</ng-template></kendo-grid-column>

  <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="{{ 'Description' | translate}}">
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" let-isNew="isNew">
  <input #input class="k-textbox" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)">
</ng-template></kendo-grid-column>

  <kendo-grid-column field="upc" title="{{ 'UPC' | translate}}" width="150">
<ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-column="column" let-formGroup="formGroup" let-isNew="isNew">
  <input #input class="k-textbox" [formControl]="formGroup.get(column.field)">
</ng-template></kendo-grid-column>

<kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx" [fetchData]="allData"></kendo-grid-excel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way

```
  <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx">
<kendo-excelexport-column field="manufactureCode" title="MFG">
</kendo-excelexport-column>
<kendo-excelexport-column field="partNo" title="Part">
</kendo-excelexport-column>
<kendo-excelexport-column field="size" title="Size">
</kendo-excelexport-column>
<kendo-excelexport-column field="name" title="Description">
</kendo-excelexport-column>
<kendo-excelexport-column field="upc" title="UPC">
</kendo-excelexport-column>
```